# How would I format console output in python correctly?

Tags: python, terminal, console, alignment, ascii

```py
from colorama import Fore
import platform
import distro
import time
import os

# Functions
def get_uptime():
    return os.popen('uptime -p').read()[:-1]

def get_os():
    return platform.system() + " " + platform.release()

# Main Entry
def main():
    linux_distro = distro.name()
    os_string = f"OS: {get_os()}"
    uptime_str = f"Uptime: {get_uptime()}"
    if 'pop' in linux_distro.lower():
        print(Fore.CYAN + f"""


            ←←←←←←←←←←←              ╠═══════════════ ROGUE FETCH ═════════════════════════════╣
        ←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←          ╠  {os_string}                                            ╣
      ←←←←←←    ←←←←←←←←←←←←←        ╠                                                         ╣
    ←←←←←         ↖←←←←←←←←←←←←      ╠  {uptime_str}                                           ╣
   ←←←←     ←←      ←←←←←←←←←←←←     ╠                                                         ╣
 ↖←←←←←     ←←←     ←←←←←←←←←←←←←↖   ╠                                                         ╣
 ←←←←←←←     ←←←    ←←←    ↖←←←←←←   ╠                                                         ╣
←←←←←←←←←     ←↖   ↖←←↖    ←←←←←←←←  ╠═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
←←←←←←←←←←        ←←←←    ↖←←←←←←←←
←←←←←←←←←←←    ↖←←←←←←   ↖←←←←←←←←←
←←←←←←←←←←←←    ←←←←←←  ←←←←←←←←←←←
←←←←←←←←←←←←←    ←←←←←↖←←←←←←←←←←←←
 ←←←←←←←←←←←←←   ↖←←←↖ ←←←←←←←←←←← 
 ↖←←←←←←←←←←←←←  ←←←←  ←←←←←←←←←←↖ 
   ←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←   
    ←←←←                   ←←←←    
      ←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←      
        ←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←        
            ←←←←←←←←←←←            
  
        """)
```

I made the frame with the symbols, however on running, it looks like unaligned and looks wrong:
link: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1164305090144915556/1170754515495030895/image.png?ex=655a311c&is=6547bc1c&hm=41877fdc735ae2b06a1c7588f7c7ba397c2dd69cf8229d2ef6df6348379263f9&=&width=1160&height=487

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format the string within the f string variable definition.  For example all of these print with a bar on each side with a 25 character fields between them.  figure out how wide you need for the var string you are using and make it that big and add remaining spaces as needed.

```
print(f"|{variable:25}|")    # default formating, string left justified, numeric right
print(f"|{variable:>25}|")   # right justifed
print(f"|{variable:<25}|")   # left justifed
print(f"|{variable:^25}|")   # center justified
```

I reworked your code so it would work locally to give you idea what I mean:

```
import platform
import os

# Functions

def get_os():
    return platform.system() + " " + platform.release()

# Main Entry
def main():
    os_string = f"OS: {get_os()}"
    print( f"""


            ←←←←←←←←←←←              ╠═══════════════ ROGUE FETCH ═════════════════════════════╣
        ←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←          ╠  {os_string:<25}                              ╣
      ←←←←←←    ←←←←←←←←←←←←←        ╠                                                         ╣
    ←←←←←         ↖←←←←←←←←←←←←      ╠                                                         ╣
   ←←←←     ←←      ←←←←←←←←←←←←     ╠                                                         ╣
 ↖←←←←←     ←←←     ←←←←←←←←←←←←←↖   ╠                                                         ╣
 ←←←←←←←     ←←←    ←←←    ↖←←←←←←   ╠                                                         ╣
←←←←←←←←←     ←↖   ↖←←↖    ←←←←←←←←  ╠═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
←←←←←←←←←←        ←←←←    ↖←←←←←←←←
←←←←←←←←←←←    ↖←←←←←←   ↖←←←←←←←←←
←←←←←←←←←←←←    ←←←←←←  ←←←←←←←←←←←
←←←←←←←←←←←←←    ←←←←←↖←←←←←←←←←←←←
 ←←←←←←←←←←←←←   ↖←←←↖ ←←←←←←←←←←← 
 ↖←←←←←←←←←←←←←  ←←←←  ←←←←←←←←←←↖ 
   ←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←   
    ←←←←                   ←←←←    
      ←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←      
        ←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←        
            ←←←←←←←←←←←            
  
        """)
    

main()
```

i received the following as output:

```
            ←←←←←←←←←←←              ╠═══════════════ ROGUE FETCH ═════════════════════════════╣
        ←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←          ╠  OS: Windows 11                                         ╣
      ←←←←←←    ←←←←←←←←←←←←←        ╠                                                         ╣
    ←←←←←         ↖←←←←←←←←←←←←      ╠                                                         ╣
   ←←←←     ←←      ←←←←←←←←←←←←     ╠                                                         ╣
 ↖←←←←←     ←←←     ←←←←←←←←←←←←←↖   ╠                                                         ╣
 ←←←←←←←     ←←←    ←←←    ↖←←←←←←   ╠                                                         ╣
←←←←←←←←←     ←↖   ↖←←↖    ←←←←←←←←  ╠═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
←←←←←←←←←←        ←←←←    ↖←←←←←←←←
←←←←←←←←←←←    ↖←←←←←←   ↖←←←←←←←←←
←←←←←←←←←←←←    ←←←←←←  ←←←←←←←←←←←
←←←←←←←←←←←←←    ←←←←←↖←←←←←←←←←←←←
 ←←←←←←←←←←←←←   ↖←←←↖ ←←←←←←←←←←←
 ↖←←←←←←←←←←←←←  ←←←←  ←←←←←←←←←←↖
   ←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←
    ←←←←                   ←←←←
      ←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←
        ←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←
            ←←←←←←←←←←←
```

Comment: problem is the string is not always going to be the same size, for example different systems will have a shorter/longer `os_string` and i need to automatically align them

Comment: @storm what I gave you will give you 25 characters of space to fit the string it,  if you need 50 characters of space then have the number be 50.  in your case use the left justified form of a variable: {os_string:<25}  in that case it will ALWAYS pad it to 25 characters even if the os string is 10.  that should allow you to finish formating the output correctly.  similar handling for uptime_str

Comment: @Storm taking it a little farther if your box were say 35 characters wide when you enter your code you would have 10 additional spaces between your vertical bars to pad out the formatted string to keep the bars aligned with the other lines.

Answer (score 0):

You have aligned the text according to "{uptime_str}" length instead of the actual length of the string contained. There is mismatch between the alignment in your source code and the visual output.

Use `len(uptime_str)` and then some padding mechanism like:

`"mystring".rjust(how_much_to_pad)` or

`"mystring".ljust(how_much_to_pad)` or

`" " * len(uptime_str)`

The same problem applies to your `os_string`

Comment: Tried that already, did not work

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: I've tried using ljust, however the alignment is still messed up even after

Comment: Please update your question with an example of those two lines how you would want to see them.

Comment: Like the other ones, properly aligned to the side

Comment: That's not an answer. What should it look like with `os_string` on the line?

Comment: Like you see in the code, `{os_string}                                            ╣` that line should exactly look the same as all the other ones, but on execution it looks unaligned

Comment: But when you have an `f-string`, the characters `{os_string}` get replaced with other data that you haven't controlled the width of. What if `os_string` is hundreds of characters long?

Comment: I don't think a version number will be 100 characters long.

Comment: So, what about 99 characters? Your "field" is about 50-60 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify the minimum and maximum field width to be the same.

I have selected 50 chars here:

```py
                    print(Fore.CYAN + f"""


            ←←←←←←←←←←←              ╠═══════════════ ROGUE FETCH ═════════════════════════════╣
        ←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←          ╠  {                                 os_string:50.50}     ╣
      ←←←←←←    ←←←←←←←←←←←←←        ╠                                                         ╣
    ←←←←←         ↖←←←←←←←←←←←←      ╠  {                                uptime_str:50.50}     ╣
   ←←←←     ←←      ←←←←←←←←←←←←     ╠                                                         ╣
 ↖←←←←←     ←←←     ←←←←←←←←←←←←←↖   ╠                                                         ╣
 ←←←←←←←     ←←←    ←←←    ↖←←←←←←   ╠                                                         ╣
←←←←←←←←←     ←↖   ↖←←↖    ←←←←←←←←  ╠═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
←←←←←←←←←←        ←←←←    ↖←←←←←←←←
←←←←←←←←←←←    ↖←←←←←←   ↖←←←←←←←←←
←←←←←←←←←←←←    ←←←←←←  ←←←←←←←←←←←
←←←←←←←←←←←←←    ←←←←←↖←←←←←←←←←←←←
 ←←←←←←←←←←←←←   ↖←←←↖ ←←←←←←←←←←← 
 ↖←←←←←←←←←←←←←  ←←←←  ←←←←←←←←←←↖ 
   ←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←   
    ←←←←                   ←←←←    
      ←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←      
        ←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←        
            ←←←←←←←←←←←            
  
        """)
```